# Downloading and executing EXE's with Windows Universal

Tags: c#, security, process, execute, win-universal-app

Im porting an app from XPe to WinRT, which runs on 1000's of machines remotely, it downloads a few other critical exe's and runs them, occasionally updating them etc.

I'm a bit concerned that unlike in XPe this may somehow be a big no-no for security reasons. No I don't want to use any kind of generic update process.

Can anyone comment on the feasibility of this? Im a bit afraid I'll hit a brick wall from security point of view. As so far WinRT seems very restrictive by comparison, bit like Android where everything is an app etc..

(PS. this is a corporate project, the machines are embedded and completely owned by us.)

Comment: Are the downloaded EXE's from an external source, or internal on your network? If they are pushed internally, I see no security threat. You could also establish a VPN if you already remotely access the machines. This would also be a secure option.

Comment: This is an internal network. Im just wondering if the whole model may simply not be feasible anymore. But, these extra modules, will have the same limitations as the parent app, so it's basically updating itself. But of course we don't want to rewrite those from scratch but reuse them as much as possible.